# make laravel system to work on cloud

Tags: php, laravel, cloud

I developed hotspot system which is working on local host and I wish to sell it on cloud . but I don't know how cloud is working and what is the  best way to make my system suitable for cloud . my system depending on database . so every new client must has his own database . so how can  I determine which database system must connect when one client trying to log in to his account

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your question is that every client has their own database? If that's the case, implementation of many database for every client is a very erroneous implementation. Just put them in one database and every client has their own data processing in your system.

Comment: but that will make data retrieving is so slowly because I assume every client will  has many and many records

Comment: That's why indexing in databases are created to make the query faster. It really depends on how you optimize your database. Also if we go with your implementation, the server still shares the processing of your other databases that still affects your other databases.